# Junit Testing Constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, testing, junit, constructor

So for my programming class, we are supposed to make a Junit test for one of our classes that inherits from an abstract class. I've just been really confused on writing Junit tests since I don't feel like there's enough examples online. My first question is, do we test getters and setters? My professor instructed us to "select all" the methods when setting up our test, but on a website she asked us to read, they advised not to test getters and setters because JVM already has testers for them. My second and most important question is can you test an entire constructor? My code below basically has an undergrad student inheriting from an abstract student class. I'm assuming I should test to make sure that the undergrad student is in fact an undergrad student and not a master student, but I don't know how to exactly test an entire constructor. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!!

```
public abstract class AbstractStudent {

/**
 * First name of a student.
 */
private String myFirstName;

/**
 * Last name of a student.
 */
private String myLastName;

/**
 * Student 9-digit ID.
 */
private String myID;

/**
 * Number of credit hours completed by a student.
 */
private int myCreditHours;

/**
 * Current student GPA.
 */
private double myGPA;

/**
 * Student gender.
 */
private Gender myGender;

/** Student date of birth.
 * 
 */
private Date myBirth;

/**
 * Private constructor to prohibit default instantiation.
 */

/**
 * @param theFirstName Adds the first name into the constructor
 * @param theLastName Adds the last name into the constructor
 * @param theID Adds the ID into the constructor
 * @param theCreditHours Adds the credit hours into the constructor
 * @param theGPA Adds the GPA into the constructor
 * @param theGender Adds the gender into the constructor
 * @param theBirth Adds the birth into the constructor
 */
public AbstractStudent(final String theFirstName, final String theLastName,
                       final String theID, final int theCreditHours, final double theGPA,
                       final Gender theGender, final Date theBirth) {

    myFirstName = theFirstName;
    myLastName = theLastName;
    myID = theID;
    myCreditHours = theCreditHours;
    myGPA = theGPA;
    myGender = theGender;
    myBirth = new Date(theBirth.getTime());

}
```

And the UndergradStudent class:

```
public class UndergradStudent extends AbstractStudent {


/** 
 * Student status.
 */
private StudentStatus myStatus;

/**
 * Parameterized constructor - constructors a Student object.
 * @param theFirstName is a string representing the first name of a student, != null
 * @param theLastName is a string representing the last name of a student, != null
 * @param theID is a string of 9 characters representing student ID
 * @param theCreditHours is an integer number >=0 representing number of credit hours 
 *          taken by a student
 * @param theGPA is a double number representing GPA, a GPA must be >= 0 and <= 4.0
 * @param theStatus is a string representing student status, != null
 * @param theGender is a character representing student gender, != null
 * @param theBirth is a date representing student birth date; a student cannot be younger 
 *          than 10 years old 
 * @custom.post Student object constructed; if invalid parameters passed, 
 *          student is in an invalid state.
 */
public UndergradStudent(final String theFirstName, final String theLastName,
                        final String theID, final int theCreditHours, final double theGPA,
                        final StudentStatus theStatus, final Gender theGender, 
                        final Date theBirth) {
    super(theFirstName, theLastName, theID, theCreditHours, theGPA, theGender, theBirth);
    myStatus = theStatus;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion testing getters and setters is not important, unless they contain business logic (such logic should not reside there anyway). Stick to the mantra of testing important parts of your application rather than making code coverage your goal.

Comment: So can I create a single test method containing the entire constructor or are you saying I should just test certain fields ex: first name, last name, gpa, etc. I just feel like if I made a separate test method for each thing, it would take up a ton of space. Thanks!

Comment: Test methods, not fields and dont worry about the number of tests you have, just ensure they are testing distinct pieces of logic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really comment on the intention of your professor but when writing unit tests you are aiming to test single units of functionality.  Most developers consider testing basic [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) behaviour where a get method returns a constructor property as redundant, however if you are writing getter/setter methods which are stateful they are worth testing.

One way you could test the whole constructor of `UndergradStudent` is to construct an instance either as a private final variable or using JUnit's [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation and writing a separate [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) for each property getter.